# Java count each value of integer

Tags: java, android

i want to have counter for each value of integer from `0` to `9`. reset that and start for next value of integer. for example i have this value : `11111` my application must be start first value of that `1` and start counter that and stop by random between `0` and `9`. after finish that i must be have like with `51111`.start again for second value of that. `for` in java must be work all values. in this sample my string lenght of that is `5` and each counter for values must be dispaly and have `delay`.

[image]

[LIKE WITH THIS LINK](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/dlwgj)

**UPDATE:**
my below code is not correct and does not work correctly.
my simple code is:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private String counter = "11111";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        int lenght = counter.length();

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= lenght; i++) {
            String letter = counter.substring(0, lenght - i);
            Integer value = Integer.valueOf(letter);
            Random rand = new Random();

            int  rnd = rand.nextInt(1000);

            for (int k = 0; k <= rnd ; k++) {
                try {
                    value += count;
                    int result = counter[letter] = value;
                    txt.setText(String.valueOf( result ));
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    if (count == 9) count = 0;

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to have counter for each value of 11111 and display it

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: @ajb my code is not correct and does not work correctly.

Comment: Please explain, "does not work correctly". Such as, current output versus expected output

Comment: @codeMagic that have problem and i can not get any good result of that

Comment: `counter[letter]` won't compile, because `counter` is a `String` and not an array, and `letter` is a `String` and not an integer. Unfortunately, I have no idea what you're trying to do.  And I am sure that is not the only problem.

Comment: I understand you are having a problem or else you wouldn't post. Reread my previous comment.

Comment: @codeMagic my code is not correct and i want to have counter for each value of `11111` and display it

Comment: @codeMagic can you help me to fix and resolve problem? i can not

Comment: You need to be more specific than "I have a problem" or "my code is not correct".  If the compiler is giving you an error you don't understand, please tell us what it is.  If you are getting an exception, please tell us what it is.  If your program is running but giving you the wrong output, please tell us what output you're seeing and what how it's different from what you're expecting.  But so far you've hidden all that information from us.  You will never get any help on StackOverflow that way.

Answer (score 1):

Never block your UI thread which can cause unexpected result, instead you can use Handler that counts each seconds and random the number for every passed second.

**sample:**

```
//////GLOBAL INSTANCE//////
String counter = "11111"; 
int counterString = 0;
Handler hand;
Runnable runnner;
int lenght = counter.length() + 1;
////////////////////////////
```

In the method where you want to call it:

```
hand = new Handler();
    final Random rand = new Random();
    runnner = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(counterString < lenght)
            {
                int ranodomInt = rand.nextInt(9);
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(counter);
                s.replace(counterString, counterString+1, ranodomInt+"");
                counter = s.toString();
                Log.d("result:", counter);
                counterString++;
                hand.postDelayed(runnner, 1000);
            }

        }
    };
    hand.post(runnner);
```

**result:**

```
08-22 19:30:21.416: D/result:(1599): 71111
08-22 19:30:22.416: D/result:(1599): 74111
08-22 19:30:23.431: D/result:(1599): 74111
08-22 19:30:24.436: D/result:(1599): 74181
08-22 19:30:25.446: D/result:(1599): 74182
```

The above code will update and edit the string `counter` to random each of the characters